# ‘like hell!’ as a strong negative

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

I try to conduct all my conversations in Latin with my close friends and am trying to find a good Latin equivalent for ‘like hell!’ as a strong negative. Would minime gentium be a good response’ when it means in an angry and forceful way that one does not agree?
"It's your fault!" "Like hell it is!" tua est culpa.  minime gentium est!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tū crēdō aliquid rhētoricum tragicumve quaeris, cui rei 'minimē gentium' mihi parum satis facere vidētur; id persuādentis vel ōrantis est potius, abhorrentis etiam.

- *quasi vērō!* – id optumē per **īrōniam** dīxeris: 'yeah right!'

  - simile sed affirmantis est, *minimē vērō!*
- *hau(d)quāquam, nēquāquam* mea est!

  - rārius et crēdō cotīdiānius, *nūllō genere!*

    - tum praecīdentis et plānē negantis illud: *neutiquam.*
- *nē tantillum quidem!* – sī dē quantitāte agitur, vel item per figūram, velut sī digitō mōnstrārēs. Hīc mihi mente fingō puerulum irrīdentem et linguam exserentem: *bae!*
- *immō tua!* dēnique, locūtiō quae est numquam nōn opportūna.

Praetera multās optumās locūtiōnēs irrīdentis atque vehementer negantis hōc locō jam prōposuī: [Expressions of contempt or credulity in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/17965/2389).

Comment: gratias tibi, mi amice Scytha humanissime. quae proposuisti mihi praegrata sunt. interjectionem 'bae' tamen non intellexi. 'babae' dicere voluisti? mihi semper placent ea quae in hac pagina electronica scripsisti. gratias quoque d-e.

Comment: @JonathanHadfield Victor Iōhannō salūtem. *bae!* illō puerum linguam exserentem significāre voluī. Namque quā interjectiōne puerī Rōmānī ūsī sint, īnfēliciter nōn trāditum est nōbīs, ergō conjectūram fēcī ex ipsō sonō :-) —Grātiās autem libenter accipiō libenterque opem ferre pergō! Cēterum, quod veniā tuā dictum sit, nōlī oblīvīscī sagittulam sūrsum premere, namque aliōquīn dubium restat et nōbīs quī respondimus et aliīs legentibus.

Comment: @JonathanHadfield Invēnī vōcem similem in Britanniā dīcī ut "nyah-nyah" et in Italia "gnee-gnee-gnee", vērum nōn compertum habeō utrum id puerī dīcant aliquid negantēs sē datūrum vel factūrum, ac linguam ostendentēs. crēdō magis lacessantēs irritantēsque; at ego aliud quaesīvī.

Answer (score 2):

One option to express strong/complete mistake would be **toto caelo errare** which [L&S has](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=caelum2&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059): "to err very much, be much or entirely mistaken". This probably less passionate response than some other options, but it might work.

This is apparently the only occasion it was used:

> Tunc Evangelus: ‘numquamne tibi, Praetextate, venit in mentem **toto**, ut aiunt, **caelo errasse** Vergilium cum Dido sua rem divinam pro nuptiis faceret? (Macrobius. Saturnalia. 3, 12, 10)
>
> [Has it never occurred to you, Praetextatus,’ Evangelus said, ‘that
> Virgil **was miles off**, as they say, when his Dido offers a
> sacrifice on behalf of her marriage? - loeb translation].